# Pause plugin module Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sleep

My script uses "plugins" that i have made out of other scripts one uses Pyttsx. If i used the sleep function in that script nothing else will continue until sleep is over.

Is there a way to make only that module sleep and rest keep running ?

cheers

Shaggs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put plugins in another thread and sleep. Anything in the main process will not be affected by the thread. Here is instruction for thread in Python. Hope it helps.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html